# How to handle multiple language in jmeter?

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

Can anyone please let me know how to handle multiple language in https request?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, please elaborate. Read [ask]. Downvoted and voting to close because unclear.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's HTTP Request sampler doesn't have any limitations when it comes to
"multiple languages" support:

[image]

It might be the case you need to explicitly set [System/JMeter properties](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding) like [file.encoding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding), [`sampleresult.default.encoding`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) in order to be able to see/send the multilingual text.